# Which (if either) of these group / map implementations is more efficient?

Tags: javascript, redux, lodash

I am interested to know which of these two alternatives is more computationally efficient, if either, and why:

```
const payloadById = keyBy(action.payload.result, 'id');
state = {
  ...state,
  ...groupBy(action.payload.result.map(i => i.id), id => payloadById[id].groupingId)
}
```

vs

```
state = {
  ...state,
  ...mapValues(groupBy(action.payload.result, 'groupingId'), (v) => v.map((v) => v.id))
};
```

`keyBy`, `groupBy` and `mapValues` all come from lodash.

tia!

Edit:
jsperf test is here https://jsperf.com/reducers9999/1

So my question becomes, why the second approach is ~40% faster?

Comment: Run a jsperf test and find out

Comment: On the case! Thanks

Comment: If that is too much, you can even try `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to test performance. But just by looking, my bet is first one should be better

Comment: @Rajesh counterintuitively: https://jsperf.com/reducers9999/1